# Calculate and display deposit in cart total en check-out total

Tags: php, function, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce webshop with different kind of beers from all over the world. If you return a empty bottle you get a deposit of 0,10 or something like that. I made an ACF (Advanced Custom Field) where I can add the deposit price for an empty bottle. I managed to add this to my cart page and display it under the single price of a bottle (0,10) and under the subtotal if there are more bottles (0,40).

This is working in cart and checkout but I want to make a sum off the total deposit money if you return the bottles to the store.

How can I create a function that calculate the sum of all bottles in the cart that has a deposit?

I managed to get the first this working with this functions:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'add_deposit_value_to_cart_single' , 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'add_deposit_value_to_cart_total', 10, 3 );


/**
* Statiegeld toevoegen onder single prijs product winkelwagen
*/
function add_deposit_value_to_cart_single( $product_price, $values ) {
    $statiegeld = get_field( "statiegeld", $values['product_id']);
    $dep_total = $statiegeld;
    
    if( ! empty( $dep_total ) )
        return $product_price . '<br /><small class="deposit_label">' .  sprintf( __( 'statiegeld %s' ), wc_price( $dep_total ) ) . '</small>';
    
    return $product_price;
}

/**
* Statiegeld toevoegen aan subtotaal in winkelwagen
*/
function add_deposit_value_to_cart_total( $product_price, $values ) {
    $statiegeld = get_field( "statiegeld", $values['product_id']);
    $dep_total = $statiegeld * $values['quantity'];
    
    if( ! empty( $dep_total ) )
        
        return $product_price . '<br /><small class="deposit_label">' .  sprintf( __( 'statiegeld totaal %s' ), wc_price( $dep_total ) ) . '</small>';
    
    return $product_price;
}
```

If someone has an idea I am very grateful because I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors with the arguments of both functions.

Try this:

```
/**
* Statiegeld toevoegen onder single prijs product winkelwagen
*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'add_deposit_value_to_cart_single' , 10, 3 );
function add_deposit_value_to_cart_single( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $statiegeld = get_field( "statiegeld", $cart_item['product_id']);
    $dep_total = $statiegeld;
    
    if( ! empty( $dep_total ) )
        return $price . '<br /><small class="deposit_label">' .  sprintf( __( 'statiegeld %s' ), wc_price( $dep_total ) ) . '</small>';
    
    return $price;
}

/**
* Statiegeld toevoegen aan subtotaal in winkelwagen
*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'add_deposit_value_to_cart_total', 10, 3 );
function add_deposit_value_to_cart_total( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $statiegeld = get_field( "statiegeld", $cart_item['product_id']);
    $dep_total = $statiegeld * $cart_item['quantity'];

    if ( ! empty( $dep_total ) ) {
        return $price . '<br /><small class="deposit_label">' .  sprintf( __( 'statiegeld totaal %s' ), wc_price( $dep_total ) ) . '</small>';
    }

    return $price;
}
```

I have tested the code and it works fine. Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I made those changes but I changed the whole code and got it working now. Also showing the Total Deposit of all items in the Cart total en Check out total. Wil post it in a minute

Comment: It did not solves my problem. My problem was showing the totals of all products with a deposit in the cart summary total and on the checkout page summary total. You did not give any solution for that but you improved my code so a vote up is in place for sure. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my whole code to this and this is working. This wil show a deposit in the cart summary under the price and a total deposit if it are more items under the subtotal.

[image]

Also in the cart total summary it is displaying the depost total of all items and in checkout too.

[image]

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'add_deposit_value_to_cart_single' , 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'add_deposit_value_to_cart_total', 10, 3 );


/**
* Statiegeld toevoegen aan single product
*/
function add_deposit_value_to_cart_single( $product_price, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Get your custom fields data
    $custom_field1 = get_post_meta( $values['product_id'], '_aantal_statiegeld', true );
    //$statiegeld = get_field( "statiegeld", $values['product_id']);
    $dep_total = $custom_field1;
    
    if( ! empty( $dep_total ) )
        return $product_price . '<br /><small class="deposit_label">' .  sprintf( __( 'statiegeld %s' ), wc_price( $dep_total ) ) . '</small>';
    
    return $product_price;
}

/**
* Statiegeld toevoegen aan totaal
*/
function add_deposit_value_to_cart_total( $product_price, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Get your custom fields data
    $custom_field1 = get_post_meta( $values['product_id'], '_aantal_statiegeld', true );
    
    //$custom_field1 = get_field( "statiegeld", $values['product_id']);
    $dep_total = $custom_field1 * $values['quantity'];
    
    if( ! empty( $dep_total ) )
        return $product_price . '<br /><small class="deposit_label">' .  sprintf( __( 'statiegeld totaal %s' ), wc_price( $dep_total ) ) . '</small>';
    
    return $product_price;
}


    // Display Fields using WooCommerce Action Hook
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocom_general_product_data_custom_field' );

function woocom_general_product_data_custom_field() {
  // Create a custom text field
    // Number Field
  woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
      'id' => '_aantal_statiegeld', 
      'label' => __( 'Statiegeld', 'woocommerce' ), 
      'placeholder' => '', 
      'description' => __( 'Vul het statiegeld hier in', 'woocommerce' ),
      'type' => 'number', 
      'custom_attributes' => array(
         'step' => 'any',
         'min' => '0,10'
      ) 
    )
  );

}

// Hook to save the data value from the custom fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocom_save_general_proddata_custom_field' );

/** Hook callback function to save custom fields information */
function woocom_save_general_proddata_custom_field( $post_id ) {

  // Save Number Field
  $number_field = $_POST['_aantal_statiegeld'];
  if( ! empty( $number_field ) ) {
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_aantal_statiegeld', esc_attr( $number_field ) );
  }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'custom_data_in_product_add_info_tab', 20, 1 );
function custom_data_in_product_add_info_tab( $product ) {

    //Product ID - WooCommerce compatibility
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    // Get your custom fields data
    $custom_field1 = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_aantal_statiegeld', true );


    // Set your custom fields labels (or names)
    $label1 = __( 'Statiegeld', 'woocommerce');


    // The Output
    echo '<h3>'. __('Statiegeld totaal', 'woocommerce') .'</h3>
    <table class="custom-fields-data">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="custom-field1">
                <th>'. $label1 .'</th>
                <td>'. $custom_field1 .'</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping', 'display_cart_volume_total', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping', 'display_cart_volume_total', 20 );
function display_cart_volume_total() {
    $total_volume = 0;

    // Loop through cart items and calculate total volume
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $product_volume = (float) get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], '_aantal_statiegeld', true );
        $total_volume  += $product_volume * $cart_item['quantity'];
    }

    if( $total_volume > 0 ){

        // The Output
        echo ' <tr class="cart-total-volume">
            <th>' . __( "Statiegeld totaal", "woocommerce" ) . '</th>
            <td data-title="total-statiegeld">€' . number_format($total_volume, 2, ',', '.') . '</td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
```